# TypeError: Cannot read property '' of undefined javascript error

Tags: javascript

So I make making a Parser and it will give me that error when I try to call my binOp function in my Parser class.
Have edited to show my full Parser code:
My code:

```js
//index.js
const fs = require('fs');
const Lexer = require('./lexer/Lexer');
const Parser = require('./Parser');

class Program {
    constructor(args) {
        this.args =  args
        this.args.shift();
        this.args.shift();
    }

    readFile(path) {
        var fileValue = fs.readFileSync(path, { encoding: 'utf-8' });
        return fileValue;
    }

    renderCommands() {
        switch(this.args[0]) {
            case 'compile':
                this.launch(this.args[0], this.readFile(this.args[1]));
                break;
        }
    }

    launch(file, data) {
        var lexer = new Lexer(file, data);
        var tokens = lexer.makeTokens();

        if(!(tokens == null)) {
            // Say tokens is ['INT:10', 'PLUS', 'INT:22']
            var parser = new Parser(tokens);
            var ast = parser.parse();
            console.log(ast.node)
        }
    }
}

var program = new Program(process.argv);
program.renderCommands()

//Parser.js
class Parser {
    constructor(tokens) {
        this.tokens = tokens
        this.tokIdx = -1
        this.advance()
    }

    advance() {
        this.tokIdx++;
        if(this.tokIdx < this.tokens.length) {
            this.currentTok = this.tokens[this.tokIdx];
        }
        return this.currentTok;
    }

    parse() {
        var res = this.expr()
        if(!res.error && this.currentTok.type != TokenTypes.EOF) {
            return res.failure(new InvalidSyntaxError(
                this.currentTok.posStart, this.currentTok.posEnd,
                "Expected '+', '-', '*' or '/'"
            ))
        }
        return res;
    }

    binOp(func, ops) {
        var res = new ParseResult();
        var left = res.register(func())
        if(res.error) return res

        while(ops.includes(this.currentTok.type)) {
            var opTok = this.currentTok;
            res.register(this.advance())
            var res = res.register(func());
            if(res.error) return res;
            left = new BinOpNode(left, opTok, right);
        }

        return res.success(left);
    }

    factor() {
        var res = new ParseResult();
        var tok = this.currentTok;

        if([TokenTypes.PLUS, TokenTypes.MINUS].includes(tok.type)) {
            res.register(this.advance())
            var factor = res.register(this.factor())
            if(res.error) return res
            return res.success(new UnaryOpNode(tok, factor));
        } else if([TokenTypes.INT, TokenTypes.FLOAT].includes(tok.type)) {
            res.register(this.advance())
            return res.success(new NumberNode(tok));
        } else if(tok.type == TokenTypes.LPAREN) {
            res.register(this.advance())
            var expr = res.register(this.expr())
            if(res.error) return res;
            if(this.currentTok.type == TokenTypes.RPAREN) {
                res.register(this.advance())
                return res.success(expr);
            } else {
                return res.failure(new InvalidSyntaxError(
                    this.currentTok.posStart, this.currentTok.posEnd,
                    "Expected '('"
                ));
            }
        }

        return res.failure(new InvalidSyntaxError(
            tok.posStart, tok.posEnd,
            "Expected int or float"
        ));
    }

    term() {
        return this.binOp(this.factor, [TokenTypes.MUL, TokenTypes.DIV]);
    }

    expr() {
        return this.binOp(this.term, [TokenTypes.PLUS, TokenTypes.MINUS]);
    }
}
```

ParseResult just has a error and node property,
When register is called it sees if res has an error,
When success is called it will set the node to the ParseResult's node
When failure is called it will check for an error then set the error

Full Error Message:

```
C:\Users\adnit\Desktop\Amethyst\src\parser\Parser.js:66
        return this.binOp(this.factor, [TokenTypes.MUL, TokenTypes.DIV]); 
                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'binOp' of undefined
    at term (C:\Users\MiccDev\Desktop\Amethyst\src\parser\Parser.js:66:21)  
    at Parser.binOp (C:\Users\MiccDev\Desktop\Amethyst\src\parser\Parser.js:81:33)
    at Parser.expr (C:\Users\MiccDev\Desktop\Amethyst\src\parser\Parser.js:70:21)
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\MiccDev\Desktop\Amethyst\src\parser\Parser.js:22:24)
    at Program.launch (C:\Users\MiccDev\Desktop\Amethyst\src\index.js:31:30)    at Program.renderCommands (C:\Users\MiccDev\Desktop\Amethyst\src\index.js:20:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MiccDev\Desktop\Amethyst\src\index.js:39:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
```

Comment: Can you show full error message?

Comment: Error in message now.

Comment: Try move binOp upper than 'term'.

Comment: @heartleth no, that didn't work.

Comment: It looks the term() method is called without being properly bound to a Parser instance. Can you show the code where this method is called?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] that shows the described behavior.

Comment: How the `term` is getting called? `new Parser().term()` or `new Parser().term.apply(...)`

Comment: The full Parser code is now there.

Comment: We don't need the parser. We need the code where and how the parser is used so we know what `this` is (which is obviously not an instance of `Parser`)

Comment: I think `expr` is wrong. `return this.binOp(this.term, [TokenTypes.PLUS, TokenTypes.MINUS]);` 's first argument's `this` is undefind. `return this.binOp(this.term.bind(this), [TokenTypes.PLUS, TokenTypes.MINUS]);`

Comment: @FallenGalaxy_, please wait, I think this will cause issues, I am posting a response to question, please refer it.

Comment: @Wazeed I will change it if needed. Right now its working perfect!

Comment: No no, please change it to `res.register(func.bind(this)())` or `res.register(func.apply(this))`. Then only the func method is called. I am not able to edit my previous comment for 5 mins.

Answer (score 0):

Examining the class code, the class method `binOp(func, ops)`'s param `func` is possibly class method through other class methods `term()` and `expr()`. In order to run `func()` with proper instance context, please update `binOp(func, ops)` method as below:

```js
binOp(func, ops) {
    var res = new ParseResult();
    // var left = res.register(func());
    var left = res.register(func.apply(this));
    if (res.error) return res

    while (ops.includes(this.currentTok.type)) {
        var opTok = this.currentTok;
        res.register(this.advance())
        // var res = res.register(func());
        var res = res.register(func.apply(this));
        if (res.error) return res;
        left = new BinOpNode(left, opTok, right);
    }

    return res.success(left);
}
```

Comment: Doesnt work, do you mean with the this.factor.bind(this)/this.term.bind(this) calling the binOp function? Nevermind it gives an error.

Comment: I mean in `binOp` method, `func()` to be replaced either with `func.bind(this)()` or `func.apply(this)` in order that function is executed before getting registered. `func.bind(this)` only gives it's definition. Refer the answer, I have commented old code for cross checking.

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work.